# nodejs - first argument must be a string or Buffer - when using response.write with http.request

Tags: node.js, http, callback

I'm simply trying to create a node server that outputs the HTTP status of a given URL.

When I try to flush the response with res.write, I get the error: throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');

But if I replace them with console.log, everything is fine (but I need to write them to the browser not the console).

The code is

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

    request({
        uri: 'http://www.google.com',
        method: 'GET',
        maxRedirects:3
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error) {
            res.write(response.statusCode);
        } else {
            //response.end(error);
            res.write(error);
        }
    });     

    res.end();
});
server.listen(9999);
```

I believe I should add a callback somewhere but pretty confused and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that in the simplest case when parsing json in node (so, let args = JSON.parse(incomingText)) this means very simply that **the argument was missing**.  So you later try args.name and name is just not present in the incoming Text.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Request takes a callback method, its async! So I am assuming, by the time the callback is executed the `res.end()` might get called. Try closing the request within the callback.

Comment: Did that and also added .toString. Thanks much.

Comment: Seems like I forgot to. Just did it. Thx.

Comment: @umutm There are more well written and elaborate answers, you should probably accept one of them; making it visible to anyone coming to this question.

Answer (score 58):

I get this error message and it mentions `options.body`

I had this originally

```
request.post({
    url: apiServerBaseUrl + '/v1/verify',
    body: {
        email: req.user.email
    }
});
```

I changed it to this:

```
request.post({
    url: apiServerBaseUrl + '/v1/verify',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: req.user.email
    })
});
```

and it seems to work now without the error message...seems like bug though. I think this is the more official way to do it:

```
 request.post({
        url: apiServerBaseUrl + '/v1/verify',
        json: true,
        body: {
            email: req.user.email
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your problem is different, body is expected by default to be a string or Buffer.
You can also change it (to be json serializable) adding json:true to options.

Eg:
request.post({
    url: apiServerBaseUrl + '/v1/verify',
    body: { email: req.user.email },
    json: true
})

Comment: You could use this to avoid **stringify** 


```javascript
request.post({
    url: apiServerBaseUrl + '/v1/verify',
    json: {
        email: req.user.email
    }
}
```

Answer (score 54):

`response.statusCode` is a number, e.g. `response.statusCode === 200`, not `'200'`. As the error message says, `write` expects a `string` or `Buffer` object, so you must convert it.

```
res.write(response.statusCode.toString());
```

You are also correct about your callback comment though. `res.end();` should be inside the callback, just below your `write` calls.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. As a nodejs newbie, didn't know that and thanks so much.

Answer (score 14):

Well, obviously you are trying to send something which is not a string or buffer. :) It works with console, because console accepts anything. Simple example:

```
var obj = { test : "test" };
console.log( obj ); // works
res.write( obj ); // fails
```

One way to convert anything to string is to do that:

```
res.write( "" + obj );
```

whenever you are trying to send something. The other way is to call `.toString()` method:

```
res.write( obj.toString( ) );
```

Note that it still might not be what you are looking for. You should always pass strings/buffers to `.write` without such tricks.

As a side note: I assume that `request` is a asynchronous operation. If that's the case, then `res.end();` will be called before any writing, i.e. any writing will fail anyway ( because the connection will be closed at that point ). Move that line into the handler:

```
request({
    uri: 'http://www.google.com',
    method: 'GET',
    maxRedirects:3
}, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
        res.write(response.statusCode);
    } else {
        //response.end(error);
        res.write(error);
    }
    res.end( );
});
```

Comment: Thank so much for the answer and the detailed info.

And, yes, I have moved the res.end into the handler.

I have accepted @loganfsmyth as it was earlier. Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

if u want to write a JSON object to the response then change the header content type to application/json

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
var d = new Date(parseURL.query.iso);
var postData = {
    "hour" : d.getHours(),
    "minute" : d.getMinutes(),
    "second" : d.getSeconds()
}
response.write(postData)
response.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

And there is another possibility (not in this case) when working with ajax(XMLhttpRequest), while sending information back to the client end you should use **res.send(responsetext)** instead of res.end(responsetext)

Answer (score 1):

> Although the question is solved, sharing knowledge for clarification of the correct meaning of the error.

The error says that the parameter needed to the concerned breaking function is not in the required format i.e. string or Buffer

The solution is to change the parameter to string

```
breakingFunction(JSON.stringify(offendingParameter), ... other params...);
```

or buffer

```
breakingFunction(BSON.serialize(offendingParameter), ... other params...);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object

> ```
>  at write_
> ```

I was getting like the above error while I passing body data to the request module.

I have passed another parameter that is JSON: true and its working.

```
var option={
url:"https://myfirstwebsite/v1/appdata",
json:true,
body:{name:'xyz',age:30},
headers://my credential
}
rp(option)
.then((res)=>{
res.send({response:res});})
.catch((error)=>{
res.send({response:error});})
```