# TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer - Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am using soap-wsdl service and trying to send a query result to front-end service angular 4. Once I compile it, I am getting the following error from server side.

I have gone through some solutions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835582/nodejs-first-argument-must-be-a-string-or-buffer-when-using-response-write-w). Then I have declared my **res.end(test1)** inside the callback but still I am missing something ?

```js
var soap = require('strong-soap').soap;
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

function getQuery() {
  var response = db.query(aqlQuery `
                 LET startVertex = (FOR doc IN spec
                 FILTER doc.serial_no == '"123456abcde"'
                 LIMIT 2
                 RETURN doc
                 )[0]

                FOR v IN 1 ANY startVertex belongs_to
                RETURN v.ip`, {
    bindVar1: 'value',
    bindVar2: 'value',
  });
  console.log("response is " + response);
  return response;

}
var checkUserName = {
  CheckUserName_Service: {
    CheckUserName_Port: {
      checkUserName: function(args, cb, soapHeader, req) {
        var query = getQuery();
        return query.then(function(response) {
          console.log("response is " + JSON.stringify(response._result));

          var soap_msg = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:examples:CheckUserNameService">' +
            '<soapenv:Header/>' +
            '<soapenv:Body>' +
            '<urn:CheckUserNameResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' +
            '<status xsi:type="xsd:string">' + JSON.stringify(response._result) + '</status>' +
            '</urn:CheckUserNameResponse>' +
            '</soapenv:Body>' +
            '</soapenv:Envelope>';
        });
   }
  }
};
var wsdl = require('fs').readFileSync('check_username.wsdl', 'utf8');
var requestCont = {
  requestHandler: function(req, res) {
    var test1 = checkUserName.CheckUserName_Service.CheckUserName_Port.checkUserName('OMG', null, null, null);

    console.log(test1);
    res.end(test1);
  }
};
server = http.createServer(requestCont.requestHandler);

server.listen(8000);
soap.listen(server, '/var/www/html/test/', checkUserName, wsdl);
```

[image]

Comment: A guess is to check the `res.end` arguements. I see two `res.end` in the above snipped. Make sure that both cases has valid buffer/string as arguement when invoked

Comment: @Malice I have reworked the code..,there is only one res.end()

Comment: What does the `console.log` before  the  `res.end`  print?

Comment: @Malice surprisingly Nothing is printed

Comment: You might want to add more logs, I think it's an error in some other part of the code

Comment: yes I did..,the whole function is not executed..,consoles outside of it has been printed